# I/ install libraries in my device and they install properly but still when i run the code, it gives me ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

i am currently using python 3.12 on Windows 11. I want to use the nsepython library in my project and installed the same. It shows that it is installed successfully but when I try to run my code, it shows the message "no module named 'nsepython'". This has happened earlier with 'Dash' library too and i had to regretfully give up on that project. I really need a solution for this issue once and for all, Please help me solve this.

I installed the nsepython library in my PC and imported it in my code. The code shows no errors and that all imports are resolved. I naturally expected my code to run successfully However, when I execute my code, I get an error message of 'NoModuleFound'.

Comment: Just like before: you installed it _how_? (there are far too many Python install managers, as well as global vs. contained ways to install packages to leave that information out) And then you imported it _how_? (show your [mcve] code). Just like last time, you really do need to include [all the details in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip install nsepython`? How did you install these libraries? Have you recently upgraded version of python or perhaps using a virtual env?  If you do `python --version` do you see v 3.12

Comment: perhaps your python cannot find the package. Do you have multiple versions of python installed?